# put Tabbar in the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs

I want to put the tabbar widget on the button of the screen but i failed. here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

I am using android 2.3.3

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:padding="3dp">
       <FrameLayout
           android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1" />
       <TabWidget
           android:id="@android:id/tabs"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignBottom = "@android:id/tabcontent"
           />
    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```